# PCA Derivation with maximizing projection length

Tags: pca, matrix

I was reading a post about deriving PCA, So it considered an arbitrary row datum, $x_i$ and tried to maximize projection length for each row of data matrix, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N(u_1.x_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(u_1.x_i)(u_1.x_i)=u_1^\top \Biggr[ \sum_{i=1}^Nx_ix_i^\top \Biggr] u_1\stackrel{*}{=}u_1^\top X^\top X u_1$$

Up to step *, everything is great, but I don't realize why the step * holds?

Comment: I only see step *, where is step ⋆?

Comment: @mhdadk Just a wrong character, fixed!

Comment: "The goal of this thesis is to modify projection pursuit by trading accuracy for interpretability. The modification produces a more parsimonious and understandable model without sacrificing the structure which projection pursuit seeks."  https://www.rand.org/pubs/external_publications/EP51086.html

Comment: @MikeHunter Didn't catch that. I am a newbie.

Comment: @MikeHunter No, and I think it is way too complicated for me! I am just a junior student self-studying an introductory course to machine learning.

Comment: The final step relies on the definition of matrix multiplication: that's all that's going on.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a typo here since $x_ix_i^T$ is a scalar value if $x_i$ is a row vector. What the author likely meant is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N(u_1\cdot x_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(u_1\cdot x_i)(u_1\cdot x_i)=u_1^\top \Biggr[ \sum_{i=1}^Nx_i^\top x_i \Biggr] u_1\stackrel{*}{=}u_1^\top X^\top X u_1
$$
where $x_i^\top x_i$ is an outer product ($D \times D$ matrix). In this case, we have
\begin{align}
X^\top X &= \begin{bmatrix}x_1^\top & x_2^\top & \cdots & x_N^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_N\end{bmatrix} \\
&= x_1^\top x_1 + \cdots + x_N^\top x_N \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^Nx_i^\top x_i
\end{align}

Comment: Yes I think this makes sense, by the way how did you derive the second equality?

Comment: @user21232681 the second equality is just a result of the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: The initial expression in the chain of equalities in the question makes sense only when $x_i$ is a *column* vector, not a row vector.

Comment: @whuber which part are you referring to exactly? I'm a bit tied up with something, so feel free to edit my answer to make any corrections.

Comment: "$u_i\cdot x_i.$"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this may be easier to see with $D=2$. In this case, you have

\begin{align*}
X^\top X & = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & x_{11}\\
    1       & x_{12}\\
\ldots\\
    1       & x_{1N}\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbb{1}^\top \mathbb{1}       & x_{\bullet1}^\top\mathbb{1}\\
    x_{\bullet1}^\top\mathbb{1}       & x_{\bullet1}^\top x_{1\bullet}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
    1+1+\cdots+1       & x_{11}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{1N}\\
x_{11}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{1N}       & x_{11}^2+x_{12}^2+\cdots+x_{1N}^2\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & x_{11}\\
x_{11}       & x_{11}^2\\
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & x_{12}\\
x_{12}       & x_{12}^2\\
\end{bmatrix} + \cdots +
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & x_{1N}\\
x_{1N}       & x_{1N}^2\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= x_{1}x_1^{\top} + x_{2}x_2^{\top}+\cdots+x_{N}x_N^{\top}\\
&= \sum_{I=1}^N x_i x_i^\top.
\end{align*}

Unless otherwise stated, all vectors are column vectors. I've used $x_{\bullet1}$ to denote the second column of $X = (x_{ij})$, $x_{j}$ to denote the $j$th row of $X$ (treated to be a column vector) and $\mathbb{1} = (1,1,\ldots,1)$ vector of length $N$.

Comment: I think $x_i x_i^\top$ is a scalar not a matrix, am I right? seems that the correct equality is $x_i^\top x_i$ but in this way I don't know how we can change the second equality in main question to $x_i^\top x_i$ instead of $x_i x_i^\top$

Comment: @user21232681 t depends on how you see the $i$th row of $X$. If you see it as a column vector, as I do, then $x_i x_i^\top$ is the correct formula. mhdadk (+1) considers these to be row vectors, which explains the difference in notation.